# sort lines according to day

Tags: date, sort

I have a text file in following format, and I need to sort the lines according to date. Is there some simple way to do it (preferably in bash) ?

```
2013-May-30     2
2013-May-21     10
2013-Jun-27     8
2013-Jun-18     9
2013-Jun-09     17
2013-May-20     21
2013-Jun-10     1
2013-Jun-01     2
2013-Aug-09     6
2013-Aug-08     5
2013-Aug-07     2
...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you tell GNU `sort` to split the fields by a different character, a dash `-` in your case it's pretty easy to sort this:

```
$ sort -n -t"-" -k1 -k2M -k3 file.txt
```

#### Example

```
$ sort -n -t"-" -k1 -k2M -k3 file.txt
2013-May-20     21
2013-May-21     10
2013-May-30     2
2013-Jun-01     2
2013-Jun-09     17
2013-Jun-10     1
2013-Jun-18     9
2013-Jun-27     8
2013-Aug-07     2
2013-Aug-08     5
2013-Aug-09     6
```

#### Reference

- [Sort field by date mm/dd/yyyy](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/131166-sort-field-date-mm-dd-yyyy.html)

Answer (score 4):

If your `sort` is not the GNU sort and doesn't support sorting by month names, you'd need to convert those month names to something your `sort` can sort on:

```
sed 's/$/-Jan1Feb2Mar3Apr4May5Jun6Jul7Aug8Sep9Oct10Nov11Dec12/
     s/-\(...\)\(.*\)-.*\1\([0-9]*\)[^-]*$/-\3\1\2/' |
  sort -nt- -k1 -k2 -k3 |
  sed 's/-./-/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You can do something like:

> sort -k 2,2n -k 3
>   Sort data using the given column number. The option -k 2,2n -k 3 sorts each column. First, it will sort 2nd column (date mm field) and then 3rd column (day).

More info can be found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-sort-date-data-using-sortcommand/).