# How to obtain the last recently three dates of a file log?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, date, sort

How can I print the last three dates of the next output:

```
User;month/day/year

    user1:01/01/2015
    user1:01/01/2015
    user1:01/01/2015
    ...
    user1:01/09/2018
    user1:01/08/2018
    user1:01/07/2018
    user1:01/04/2016
    user1:01/02/2016
    user1:01/01/2016
```

*In this case (the 2018 dates)*

**EDIT:**

I have the next command with awk:

```
awk '{ print $1":" substr( $0,285,291 )}' $file_input | awk '{ print $1}' | sort -n -r
```

**Desired Output:**

```
    user1:01/09/2018
    user1:01/08/2018
    user1:01/07/2018
```

Comment: Is that `mm/dd/YYYY` (USA) or `dd/mm/YYYY`? I'd recommend using `YYYY-mm-dd` which is unambiguous and easier to sort.

Comment: Oh my fault, my file input has USA dates (mm/dd/YYYY). Is there another way to sort it without change the format?

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86413/sort-lines-according-to-day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, sort on the `YYYY` part and then on the `mm/dd` part lexically.

That would be the 7<sup>th</sup> to 10<sup>th</sup> characters and 1<sup>st</sup> to 5<sup>th</sup> of the second `:`-delimited field respectively, so:

```
<file sort -r -b -t: -k2.7,2.10 -k 2.1,2.5 | head -n 3
```

(here adding a `-b` to allow (and ignore) blanks around the `:`)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using sort like this:

```
sort -rt/ -k3n -k1.11n -k2n < input | head -3
```

This sorts the lines based on 3 key fields, based on a `/` delimiter: first the year, then the month (field 1, skipping past the username and colon), then field 2 -- all numerically sorted.  The `tail -3` outputs only the last (latest) 3 lines/dates.

Comment: Or `sort -rbt: -k2.7,2.10 -k2.1,2.5 | head -n3`